# Ошибка "Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet" при установке MySQL на Debian 10

Tags: mysql, debian, установка

Пытался установить MySQL на сервер, но увы, даже при многочисленных переустановок, более 6-ти часов, проведенные за поиском решения проблемы, проблема не была устранена. Сколько раз и что бы я не делал перед очередной попыткой установить MySQL, каждый раз выводится ошибка *"dpkg: /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"*, а во время установки - *"Package mysql-community server is not configured yet"*. Окно с вводом пароля для mysql появлялось и всё проходило без проблем. Также, при некоторых попытках окно конфигурации (где нужно выбрать версию mysql) отображалось 3 раза. Удалял всё, что связано с mysql перед каждой установкой (apt remove ..., apt clean, apt-get autoremove, удаление папок, и прочие действия, связанные с чисткой). Обычная установка через *apt-get install mysql-server* не работает - выводит:

```
Package mysql-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Что делать больше не знаю. Искал информацию на разных источниках, но ничего не помогло.
Скриншоты консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса 2. не стоит устанавливать в систему «левые» пакеты при [наличии](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql-server&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) более чем официальных. 3. удалите этот «левый» пакет mysql-community-server и поставьте пакет mysql-server.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , разве "community-server" не поставляется автоматически в официальном пакете "mysql-apt-config"? В первом скриншоте написано: "mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server", но почему-то, mysql-community-server считается не сконфигурированным, хотя и пароль и версия были выбраны при установке

Comment: упоминаемые вами пакеты `mysql-community-server` и `mysql-apt-config` отсутствует в официальном репозитории дистрибутива `debian gnu/linux`. вероятно, вы скачали их с сайта mysql.com. увы, как это часто и происходит с левыми пакетами, «фокус не удался». вот я и рекомендую не пользоваться левыми источниками.

Comment: Что же тогда делать, если мне нужно управление базой данных mysql, но через apt-get mysql не устанавливается?